# Socket.io connection to node server

Tags: express, socket.io

If a browser has the node runtime, doesn’t that also contain express and  socket.io libraries? And if so, then can’t you instantiate an http server within the browser context itself?
I mean - does a socket in a browser  always act as a ‘client’ - and communicate with a backend server?

Thanks 
AV

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome browser uses the V8 engine to compile and run JavaScript. Node.js uses the same V8 engine. But that doesn't mean that the browser has node, nor does it include some of the modules like http which are necessary to run an express server.

Answer (score 0):

> If a browser has the node runtime

That is not what a browser has.  It does NOT have the node runtime.

The Chrome browser uses the V8 engine to run Javascript.  That is not a runtime library.  That is just the Javascript interpreter that makes the raw language run.  The browser then adds a library of stuff that is specific to the browser such as a DOM library and various interfaces that are browser specific such as XMLHttpRequest and others.

node.js also uses the same V8 engine for raw language support.  But, then node.js adds its own runtime library (that's where the http library is) and those libraries are not in the browser in any way.

> And if so, then can’t you instantiate an http server within the browser context itself?

No, you cannot.

> I mean - does a socket in a browser always act as a ‘client’ - and communicate with a backend server?

Browsers have two main ways of communicating with an outside server.  They can make an http request (often called an Ajax request in the context of the browser).  Or, they can make a webSocket connection to another server and exchange messages over the webSocket.  The browser would always be the client.  It would initiate the connection to some server.  There is no way for an outside agent to "connect to a user's browser".  Instead, the browser has to connect to the outside agent.

Comment: @user2736158 - Did this answer your question?